# Blank String Default Value in core data designer iphone

Tags: iphone, core-data, default

Is there any way to set empty string as default value in core data
Here the problem is, it is taking blank value in sqlite table as null and I don't want it.

Thank you,
Raghu,

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this personally, but you might want to try using an encoding for a space such as "\u00A0" or maybe